# Is it possible to do a select and update it with new value in the same query?

Tags: mysql

I have tgot the following table structure

```
mysql> desc test
    -> ;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | varchar(19) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| name  | varchar(19) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age   | varchar(19) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Initialy i have done an insert as shown

```
insert into test (id, name, age) values("1", "A", 19);
```

my requirement is that , i need to extract the  age  of id "1" and add some integer to the existing age

I have seen this below example , can tis be useful in my case ??

```
insert into test (id, name, age) values("1", "A", 30) on duplicate key update  age=values(age)
```

I am using JAVA , i have symbols of 300 , for which i need to update contonouslly

Is it possible to do a select and update the existing column with new value in the same query ??

For example

how can i get the existing age 19 and add it with 30 in the same query for the id 1  ??

Comment: yes, you can do an update on a record with the `on duplicate key`, but it's only useful if you're going to be doing a PK violation with the update.

Comment: that is valid for me , could you please tell me how can i get the exiting age 19 and add it with 30 in the same query ??

Comment: `update yourtable set thefield=thefield+30`

Comment: Thanks a lot . I will try and let you know .

Comment: age? You want to store age?

Comment: @Strawberry: we need to store "age", just in case we need to calculate the "born on" date. (i kid, i kid.)

Answer (score 1):

(This question has already been answered by Marc B in the comments section.)

Yes, the statement OP has posted will work just fine, because there is a primary key constraint on the `id` column, and INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY will cause an UPDATE of the existing row.

To "add" the value being inserted to the value that already exists in the column, we'd assign an expression that does that operation to the column:

e.g.

```
insert into test (id, name, age) values("1", "A", 30) 
on duplicate key update age = age + values(age)
                              ^^^^^
```

Note that the only change required in OP statement is the reference to the existing column value and an addition operation.

N.B. If either the existing value in the column, or the new value being supplied in the INSERT statement is **NULL**, the result of the expression will be **NULL**. A different expression would be needed if this is undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE test SET age=age+1 WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: That will work, but it doesn't do what OP specified.

Comment: This seems to be the same as the answer in the comment that the OP said worked perfectly.  @spencer7593 what is the difference?

Comment: @Paul Hicks: I believe OP wanted the value being inserted (by an insert statement) to be added to the existing value of the column. OP shows a value of '19' for age in the first insert statement, and wants the value of '30' (in the second insert statement) added to the existing value of '19', so that 49 would assigned as the new value for the column. I thought OP wanted to do this with an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement. At least, that was my understanding of what OP asked for.